# Can I make biblatex refrain from assuming my postnote (which consists of a number) is a page number?

Tags: biblatex

I'm looking to cite [some papers](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/bh1.pdf) which have many sections, indicated by simply a number, e.g. 13.9. I would like to cite them and, while doing so, indicate which section the reader should look at (since the papers are very long). I naively tried `\cite[13.9]{citekey}`, but biblatex then automatically assumes that I'm trying to indicate a page number an adds `p. 13.9` instead of simply `13.9`. Is there a command that suppresses the `p.`? I assume so, but couldn't find it in the biblatex manual.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the prefix `\nopp` to the postnote: `\cite[\nopp 13.9]{citekey}`, or set the `pagination` field in `citekey`'s entry in the `.bib` file to `none`

See section 3.13.3 of the `biblatex` manual.

Answer (score 9):

From the BibLaTeX manual, section 3.13.3

> It is possible to suppress the prefix on a per-entry basis by setting
>   the pagination field of an entry to ‘none’, see § 2.3.10 for details.
>   If you do not want any prefixes at all or prefer to type them
>   manually, you can also disable the entire mechanism in the document
>   preamble or the configuration file as follows:
>   `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}`

On the other hand, when your numbers refer to sections instead of page number, it may be better to use `\cite[section 13.9]{citekey}` anyways, to make this clear to the reader, which will automatically suppress any prefix and suffix in the postnote field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since I prefer to keep the default pagination for most references, just not for this one, I will accept the other answer; don't take this to mean yours is any less useful ;-)

Comment: @Danu No problem. If you are citing this work more often, however, it would probably still be better to set the pagination field of this one entry to "none", so you do not have to remember to call `\nopp` everytime you cite this work.

Comment: That's right (unless, of course, I do want to refer to its page numbers sometime). Thanks for the remark.