# How to cite paragraphs rather than pages from bibliography reference?

Tags: biblatex, citing

Quoting a reference using `biblatex`, it is possible to add an optional argument to `cite` in order to specify the page number that is being quoted, such as in

```
\cite[20]{foo}
```

which will produce something like "[Foo, p. 20]".

My question is if there is some package or some hack that will allow to do the same without the "p.".

The goal is to be able to cite specific paragraphs, rather than pages. The paragraphs happen to be numbered by roman numerals, so the idea is to be able to do something like:

```
\citep[XXVI]{foo}
```

and get something like "[Foo, XXVI]".

Comment: See also [biblatex: How to omit “p.” at \cite?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53050/35864) and [Can I make biblatex refrain from assuming my postnote (which consists of a number) is a page number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/362109/35864)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `\nopp` to suppress the page prefix 'p.'/'pp.'

```
\cite[\nopp 20]{sigfridsson}
```

---

If you want to always suppress the page prefix, use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
```

`\mknormrange` is a fairly recent addition to `biblatex`, so if the command is undefined when you add it, you probably just want to try `#1` instead of `\mknormrange{#1}` (or say `\providecommand*{\mknormrange}[1]{#1}`).

---

If you want to suppress the 'p.'/'pp.' for a particular entry, add

```
pagination = {none},
```

to the `.bib` entry. Instead of `none`, you can also have (the default) `page` or one of `column`, `line`, `verse`, `section` or `paragraph`.

Comment: Some more detail is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/633414/35864.

Answer (score 3):

Biblatex also dissables the page prefix if you are adding the paragraph symbol.

Input:

```
\cite[\S1.2.3]{sigfridsson}
```

Output:

[Foo, §1.2.3]