# Remove the "p." from postnode

Tags: biblatex, citing, ieee-style

I need to quote from websites and i am searching for an option to add additional information to the quote **instead** of the page.

If I use for example `\cite[foo]{bar}` I would get something like `[1, p. foo]`. However,
I don't want the `"p."` in there because it could be something different than a page. Is there an option to leave that out? It is not neccessary that I use `\cite`, another command would be ok as well.

I am using:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which entry type you use for webpages and  documents stored on websites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`biblatex` can usually detect whether or not your postnote argument is a page range and will only add the "p."/"pp." prefix if it is appropriate. Consider the following example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocite[381-383]{sigfridsson}

dolor \autocite[not a page range]{sigfridsson}

sit \autocite[foo]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1, p. 380] ipsum [1, pp. 381–383] dolor [1, not a page range] sit [1, foo]]

If `biblatex`'s detection is off for some reason, you can use `\pno` and `\ppno` to force "p." and "pp." respectively, or you can use `\nopp` to stop a "p."/"pp." prefix from appearing

```
Lorem \autocite[\nopp380]{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocite[\nopp381-383]{sigfridsson}

dolor \autocite[\pno~371z]{sigfridsson}

sit \autocite[\ppno~381z-382q]{sigfridsson}
```

[image: Lorem [1, 380] ipsum [1, 381-383] dolor [1, p. 371z] sit [1, pp. 381z-382q]]

If you never want to see any automatic "p."/"pp." at all, you can get rid of it with

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocite[381-383]{sigfridsson}

dolor \autocite[not a page range]{sigfridsson}

sit \autocite[foo]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1, 380] ipsum [1, 381–383] dolor [1, not a page range] sit [1, foo]]

If you want to change the behaviour only for a specific entry, you can use the `pagination` field. `pagination = {none},` suppresses the "p."/"pp." prefix, but you can select different schemes like `verse` or `paragraph` as well.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{elk,
  author     = {Anne Elk},
  title      = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year       = {1972},
  location   = {London},
  url        = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.html},
  pagination = {none},
}
@online{elk:tri,
  author     = {Anne Elk},
  title      = {A Theory on Triceratops},
  year       = {1980},
  location   = {London},
  url        = {https://example.edu/~elk/trici.html},
  pagination = {paragraph},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[380]{sigfridsson}

ipsum \autocite[381]{elk}

dolor \autocite[382]{elk:tri}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [3, p. 380] ipsum [1, 381] dolor [2, par. 382]]

See also [How to cite paragraphs rather than pages from bibliography reference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372522/35864),

Comment: That works perfectly! I am using  Lorem \autocite[\nopp380]{sigfridsson} Thanks for the very fast and detailed help!