# citation style (Chicago but footnote only with author (year)

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[(margin=1in)]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\bibliography{ref}
```

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

Are there any ways to put authoryear in-text citation to footnote?

e.g. on strategic asset (Ding and Dafoe 2021).
--> on strategic asset1.

and at footnote,

1. Ding and Dafoe (2021).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some combination of the following `\cite` commands should do what you want.

I added one extra `\cite` macro which gives direct output like your example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric, citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\foottextcite}[\iffootnote\relax\mkbibfootnote]
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffirstcitekey
     {\setcounter{textcitetotal}{1}}
     {\stepcounter{textcitetotal}%
      \textcitedelim}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\foottextcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\foottextcite}{}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Filler text \autocite{baez/article}.

\textcite{baez/article} filler text.

Filler text.\footcite{baez/article}

Filler text.\foottextcite[7--11]{baez/article}

Filler text.\foottextcites[7--11]{baez/article}[171--178]{bertram}

Filler text.\footnote{\textcite{baez/article}.}

Filler text.\footnote{Filler text \autocite{baez/article}.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks so much! It really helped me a lot!!!! Just two questions on \foottextcites instead of \foottextcite. I command \foottextcites[7--11]{axe90}[171--178]{jer78} but it appears within the text, not in the footnote section. I think this with \footnote{\textcites[7--11]{axe90}[171--178]{jer78}.} Is this okay way to fix it, though seems right. 

+ If there are specific pages I cite, it seems like this in the footnote section: Hirschman (1980, pp. 13–33.) Instead, how can I fix the command to show like this: Hirschman (1980), 13-33.

Comment: Such a nice suggestion `+1`

Comment: @Shown, so it does! I'll have a look.

Comment: @Shown, I missed an optional argument in `\DeclareMultiCiteCommand`. Try now.

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't mind having the postnote/page range outside of the parentheses, you can use `biblatex-ext`'s cite delimiter feature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}.

Ipsum \textcite{sigfridsson} filler text.

Dolor.\footcite{sigfridsson}

Sit.\footcite[380-382]{sigfridsson}

Amet.\footcites[380-382]{sigfridsson}[24-27]{worman}

Lorem.\footnote{\textcite{sigfridsson}.}

Ipsum.\footnote{Filler text \autocite{sigfridsson}.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998), pp. 380–382; Worman (2002), pp. 24–27.]

Comment: Thanks! Just a single question to remove "pp." Is there a way to change it like this-i.e., Sigfridsoon and Ryde (1998), 380-382-instead of Sigfridsoon and Ryde (1998), "pp." 380-382

Comment: @Shown `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}`. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/633404/35864.