# Printing Chicago-styled reference

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, bibliographystyle

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}.

Ipsum \textcite{sigfridsson} filler text.

Dolor.\footcite{sigfridsson}

Sit.\footcite[380-382]{sigfridsson}

Amet.\footcites[380-382]{sigfridsson}[24-27]{worman}

Lorem.\footnote{\textcite{sigfridsson}.}

Ipsum.\footnote{Filler text \autocite{sigfridsson}.}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Image refers to [citation style (Chicago but footnote only with author (year)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668580/citation-style-chicago-but-footnote-only-with-author-year).

Based on the above code and image, how can I print Chicago-style bibliography with the name of "Reference" instead of "Bibliography"? The "\bibliographystyle{chicago}" code above doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to follow the `chicago` style exactly, then my suggestion is go with `biblatex-chicago`

Answer (score 1):

You need `\printbibliography[title={References}]`.

If you want Chicago style, though, you would be better off using `biblatex-chicago` which is designed for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Due to specific citation style that I want, I cannot change the biblatex code. Having said that, no way?